# What is jom in qt build system ? how to call jom from command line to build qt project?

Tags: c++, qt, build

Trying to build and run a simple "Hello world.." Qt application from command line, started the following steps and struck in compiling and building..
1. created main.cpp file 
2. run qmake -pro to create project file
3. run qmake to create make files
       ( here either have to run nmake or jom.. I tried jom )
4. run jom.exe makefile , but nothing happens..

so here are my questions .. 
what is jom ( and expansion ?) , 
how to invoke jom from command line..

I am using Qt 5.1.1 with Microsoft Visual C++ compiler 11.0.

Comment: Did you read this: http://qt-project.org/wiki/jom ?

Comment: Yes I did, but there is no information on how to invoke jom ! or expansion for jom

Comment: There is a link to the original post too: http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2009/03/27/speeding-up-visual-c-qt-builds/ . You simply need to use jom instead of nmake. The -j option is also available to set the number of concurrent processes.

Comment: Since jom is a drop-in replacement for nmake, just treat it like you would nmake. If, OTOH, your question is about how to find executables on your system, it really doesn't belong here - look on superuser for answers to that (hint: Windows has built-in file search).

Answer (score 19):

nmake doesn’t make use of all available processing power like GNU make. jom is a clone of nmake to support the execution of multiple independent commands in parallel. It can use an arbitrary number of processes concurrently.

When using it for example On a quad core machine with a Qt build takes half of the time it took using nmake.

You also can use the -j command line argument to set the number of concurrent processes:

```
C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -j 12 -f Makefile
```

12 represents the number of cores you want to use. I use 12 because I have 12 threads.

Comment: I tried executing this command, but it gives error "Error: File -j doesn't exist."

Comment: @Prady Try `-j %NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS%` to at least try one thread per-core compilation. `jom` is really picky sometimes.

Comment: @Prady there was a mistake in the answer that Nejat corrected, but didn't tell you about.

Answer (score 0):

As answered by (Nejat), GNU Make has some well known limitations in this topic, and it doesn't use all computing power available so I recommend using jom. 
jom is a clone of nmake to support the execution of multiple independent commands in parallel. It can use an arbitrary number of processes concurrently.

**To use Jom you must set it in the project itself not in Qt tools options:**

1. Goto the Project's build settings and under the build steps category there is a "Make" item.
2. Expand the details on that and you'll find a "Override mingw32-make.exe:" item. Paste the jom location e.g.  "C:\QtSDK\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" in there, and suddenly I was building with multiple cores.

[Steps to set up jom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfMMK.png)

All credit goes to Nejat answer above.